# Integration of $(r^k - \lvert x \rvert^k)^{1/2}$

Tags: integration

I would like to integrate for $r > 0$ and $ k\in \mathbb{N}$

$\int_{-r}^r (r^k - \lvert x \rvert^k)^{1/2} d x. $

For example when $k = 2$ we have

$ 2 \int_{-r}^r (r^2 - \lvert x \rvert^2)^{1/2} d x = \pi r^2  $

and for $k = 4$

$ \int_{-r}^r (r^4 - \lvert x \rvert^4)^{1/2} d x = \sqrt{\pi} r^3 \frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{7}{4})}. $

I believe the answer is

$\int_{-r}^r (r^k - \lvert x \rvert^k)^{1/2} d x = C_k \sqrt{\pi} r^{\frac{k}{2} + 1} $

for an appropriate constant $C_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $x=ry$, you find
$$
\int_{-r}^r (r^k-|x|^k)^{1/2}\, dx = r^{\frac{k}{2}+1} \int_{-1}^1 (1-|y|^k)^{1/2}\, dy.
$$
It seems that your conjecture is correct *only if* the number $C$ is allowed to depend on $k$ itself.

Comment: thanks, I've updated that. And simple answer, i like it.  It'd be great to find this constant.